# How can I call a functions added to the jQuery Object from my GreaseMonkey script?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, greasemonkey

I've created a GreaseMonkey script based on an in-page script that I'd like to [use on a site](https://bricks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/99/56), however I'm having the following issue:

In the script, we've created our namespace (`brickJax`) that contains the bulk of the functions, and I've required jQuery as we're using the jQuery replaceText functions as well.

When I call the `replaceText` function from `replaceSet` I get the following error on the console:

> uncaught exception: TypeError: $(node).replaceText is not a function

However, calling it as part of the `GM_xmlhttpRequest` `onload` callback works fine.

```
var brickJax = (function ($) {
  "use strict";
  var brickJax = {};

  //[Code here]

  function replaceSet(node, str, number, colour) {
    var text = '<a href="http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/' + number + '-1">'
               + number + ' on Peeron</a>';

    // THIS LINE THROWS THE ERROR:
    $(node).replaceText(str, text);
  }

  function replaceImage(node, str, number, colour) {
    getBricksForImage(number, colour, node, str);
  }

  function getBricksForImage(number, colour, node, str) {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "POST",
        url: "http://brickjax.doodle.co.uk/bricks.aspx/JsonDetails/" + number 
             + "/" + colour,
        dataType: "jsonp",
        onload: function (data) {
            // THIS CALL WORKS PERFECTLY
            $(node).replaceText(str,
                                buildImage($.parseJSON(data.responseText)));
        }
    });
  };

  function buildImage(ajaxData) {
    var text = '<img style="max-height:100px;" src="' + ajaxData.Src 
               + '" alt="' + ajaxData.AltText + '" />';

    return text;
  }

  function replaceTags(element) {
    var elements = $(element).find('*').andSelf();
    elements = elements.not($('script,noscript,style,textarea,pre,code')
                       .find('*').andSelf());

    searchText(elements, /\[part:([\w\-]*)(?::([\w\-]*))?\]/gi, replaceImage);

    searchText(elements, /\[set:([\w\-]*)(?::([\w\-]*))?\]/gi, replaceSet);
  };

})(jQuery);

brickJax.replaceTags($('body'));

(function ($) { $.fn.replaceText = function (b, a, c) { [...] } })(jQuery);
```

In the actual script I've added logging, which shows that `node` is an HTML element in both cases.

What is it that I'm doing wrong in the call from `replaceSet` that is different from the call in callback that's causing this error?

In the [hosted version](http://brickjax.doodle.co.uk/) both calls work as expected.

Apologies for the wall of script, I've tried to cut it down to the bare essentials.

Comment: Looks like it might be closure-related.  Try putting the definition of `replaceText` physically before the `var brickJax = ...` stuff.

Comment: @BrockAdams - if you'd care to post that suggestion as an answer, I'll happily accept it - worked a treat thank you, and I think I understand why ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is either closure related or due to the [function being defined in an *expression* versus a *declaration*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3887590/331508).

Either way, the solution should be the same, move the definition of `replaceText` physically before the `var brickJax = ...` stuff.