# Ajax on success not firing in mozilla

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have written a ajax method

```
if(document.URL.indexOf('LID')!=-1)
{
 $.ajax
       ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../DL/Lecture_List.aspx/GetTitle",
        data: '{LectureID:"'+document.URL.substring(document.URL.indexOf("=")+1)+'"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: SuccessHandler
       });
       function SuccessHandler(data){
        var title = data.d;
        Add_anchor(title);
       }
}
```

this code is working fine in chrome but in mozilla firefox reflexing error,

```
ReferenceError: SuccessHandler is not defined
```

Comment: Put the function in front of the Ajax call. Realistically, you could define that inline as `function(data) { Add_anchor(data.d); }`.

Comment: $.ajax
       ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../DL/Lecture_List.aspx/GetTitle",
        data: '{LectureID:"'+document.URL.substring(document.URL.indexOf("=")+1)+'"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success:  function (data){
                 var title = data.d;
                     Add_anchor(title);
                  }
       });   are you saying to write like above..?

Comment: Yes. (And the `title` variable is redundant)

Comment: That is working fine , but in some case i prefer to write onsuccess event as separate function (which will  be easy to understand). that function is working in chorme but not in firefox, is there any mistake in declaration??

Comment: No, I do not see any mistake in your declaration. I suspect you found a bug in Firefox, which is what I was trying to see with the first setence of my first comment. You may be interested in this great [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3887590/706724). Personally, it's odd to see a declaration after use, but as the answer shows, it should be syntactically valid.