# JavaScript scope gets changed? Why does this happen?

Tags: javascript, scope, hoisting

The value of 'a' seems to lose global scope when the constructor a is called.

```
var a = 6;

function b() {
    a = 10;

    function a() {}
    console.log(a); //10
}
b();
console.log(a); //6
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order is interpreted as shown below due to variable hoisting. Note that as @ShadowCreeper correctly points out, `function a(){}` is actually creating a local variable `a` inside of function b which is hoisted as shown below.

```
var a;
var b;

a = 6;
b = function() {
 var a;
 a = function(){};
 a = 10;
 console.log(a); //10
}
b();
console.log(a); //6
```

Comment: Is defining `a` as a function inside `b` forcing `a` to be local to `b` ,  even without explicitly doing a `var a`. What is the magic behind the implicit local scope?

Comment: @sabithpocker that's the default behavior of nested `function`'s, in that their local to the `function` their defined in ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope#Nested_functions_and_closures

Comment: Why does the hoisting behavior change when "function a() {}" is wrapped in parenthesis? http://jsfiddle.net/ZrgxX/

Comment: @user2430508 - Because wrapping it in parenthesis makes it an expression and scopes the function definition to that expression. Consider this: http://jsfiddle.net/eVgw3/ , where you can clearly see that `a` is locally scoped to the expression.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are creating a local variable (the function `a`) then replacing that local variable's value (the `function`) with `10`.

One way to avoid things like this is to precede all local variables and functions with "_" (underscore).

Comment: If you put `var a = 10;` at the top of the `b` function, you will have a local variable that hides the global. I believe also that `function a ()` behaves the same as `var a = function ()` (creates a local variable named `a` that is a `function`).

Comment: agreed, the implicit local declaration of the nested `function a` here is the kicker http://jsfiddle.net/AVcqr/ ...

Comment: Yes, @TravisJ explained it better though. I've never heard the term `hoisting`, that is new to me. :)

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3887590/505154) has a really nice explanation of what is going on here.

The summary is that Javascript is processed in two phases, compilation and then execution.  The function definitions occur during the compilation step, so inside of `b` the compiler sees the definition `function a() {}` and the local variable `a` is created within the scope of `b`.  Later on when the code is executed, the scope of `b` already contains the local variable `a` before any code is executed, so the line `a = 10;` is just giving the local variable a new value.  The function definition was already processed during compilation so that will not happen during execution, so `console.log(a)` will output `10`.