# Object inside of object not compiling

Tags: javascript

I have an object that holds all my global variables and I'd to add a variable now, "position,"  that is itself an object.  I tried

```
var g = {   
  var1: null,
  var2: null,
  position: {
    left: null, 
    top: null
  },
  var3: null
};
```

But this gives a compile error of:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
position.left: null,
```

The idea is to be able to set position with

```
g.position.left = "200px";
```

Does anyone see the problem here?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, check the error isn't coming from elsewhere (somewhere with a property named `id`)

Comment: Your error is being caused by code that you're not showing us

Comment: This code parses and runs just fine in Chrome.  The error is most likely in the surrounding code.  Could you post that?

Comment: Quotes around each property and it works at [jsoneditoronline](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/)

Comment: do you have `position.left: null,` anywhere in your code?

Comment: JavaScript doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  Underneath what I showed you  I had position.left: null.  'Sorry the problem wasn't more interesting but thanks for the extra eyes.

Comment: Regarding the comment "JavaScript doesn't compile" actually JavaScript is processed in two phases, a compile phase and then an interpret phase.  See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887408/javascript-function-declaration-and-evaluation-order.