# JavaScript: Position of constructor declarations relative to their use, when inside a function

Tags: javascript, constructor, declaration, evaluation

Answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887408/javascript-function-declaration-and-evaluation-order) indicate that, when a JavaScript file is read, function declarations are loaded into memory during a first pass, and expressions are evaluated in a subsequent pass. However, the example below shows that functions inside a function are compiled *after* code is executed.

To get the code below to work, I must move the `Child` constructor outside the test function or place it before the call to `new Child()` if it is to remain inside the `test` function. In its current position, you will get a `TypeError: this.init is not a method` when you run the code.

Where can I find detailed information on when function declarations s within functions are evaluated?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  test()
}, false)


function test() {
  // Child declaration can go here

  var child = new Child()

  // If Child is placed here, this.init is undefined
  function Child() {
    this.init()
  }
  Child.prototype = new Ancestor(Child)
}


function Ancestor(constructor) {
  this.constructor = constructor
}
Ancestor.prototype.init = function init() {
  console.log(this)
}

// Child declaration can go here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the *init* method comes from the *Ancestor* class. And you are inherit it after the creation of the *child* instance. For example the code below works.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    test()
}, 200);

function test() {
  // Child declaration can go here

  Child.prototype = new Ancestor(Child);
  var child = new Child();  

  // If Child is placed here, this.init is undefined
  function Child() {
    this.init()
  }

}

function Ancestor(constructor) {
  this.constructor = constructor
}
Ancestor.prototype.init = function init() {
  console.log(this)
}
```

So, just move the *Child.prototype = new Ancestor(Child)* above the calling of *new Child*. You don't need to put the Child constructor outside the *test* function.

In other words, in your example, *init* method is still not attached to the *Child* prototype when you call *new Child*.

Comment: Your answer makes perfect sense. I had been assuming that all the `Function.prototype.method = ...` calls were evaluated at the same time as the function itself is compiled, but now I understand that they are evaluated during the second pass. Your re-ordering of the lines of code makes this clear. However, the code will be more readable if the function declaration and its prototype methods are all kept together, above the call to `new Child()`.

Comment: Yep, I agree with you.