# Typescript - Can I have mutually referencing classes?

Tags: typescript

I would like to create two classes, `Parent` and `Child`, which each contain a reference to an instance of the other type.  In many compiled languages, this is perfectly legal.  For example, in C#, this compiles:

```
public class Parent {
    public Child myChild;

    public Parent() {
        myChild = new Child();
        myChild.myParent = this;
    }
}

public class Child {
    public Parent myParent;
}
```

However, in TypeScript I cannot get this to work.  The best option I have found is to make one of the references of `any` type, but this defeats any static type checking that `Child` needs to do when working with `Parent` or any of its other members.

```
class Parent {
    myChild: Child;

    constructor() {
        this.myChild = new Child();
        this.myChild.myParent = this;
    }
}

class Child {
    myParent: any;
}
```

In an ideal world, all object models would be easily describable by acyclic graphs, but the real world is messy and sometimes it is incredibly convenient to be able to navigate an object graph both ways.

Can I get two-way statically-typed object graph navigation like this in TypeScript?  How?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Circular Type References in TypeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444436/circular-type-references-in-typescript)

Comment: Works for me--what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If both classes are in the same file (module) - you should have no problems. For example the following code works just fine:

```
class Parent
{
    public myChild: Child;

    public constructor()
    {
        this.myChild = new Child();
        this.myChild.myParent = this;
    }

    public callMe()
    {
        this.myChild.callMe();
    }

    public callMeAgain()
    {
        console.log("Parent");
    }
}

class Child
{
    public myParent: Parent;

    public callMe()
    {
        console.log("Child");
        this.myParent.callMeAgain();
    }
}

let p = new Parent();
p.callMe();
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Parent%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20myChild%3A%20Child%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20constructor()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myChild%20%3D%20new%20Child()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myChild.myParent%20%3D%20this%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20callMe()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myChild.callMe()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20callMeAgain()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Parent%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20myParent%3A%20Parent%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20callMe()%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Child%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.myParent.callMeAgain()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20p%20%3D%20new%20Parent()%3B%0D%0Ap.callMe()%3B)

UPDATE.

Unfortunately even with the latest typescript 2.0.3 crossreferencing between modules will not work in general case. A little bit more complicated cross referencing case (take this as an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156414/cross-referencing-with-extended-classes-in-typescipt)) will still not work. For the reasons why you can refer to the previous link and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34810708/type-declaration-order-in-typescript/34944880#34944880)

Comment: This solution technically works, but putting everything in one file is not a very scalable solution.

Comment: I get that it works if they're in the same file, but why can't they be in different files?

Answer (score 0):

This code builds correctly for me using `TypeScript 2.0.2`:

```
class Parent {
    myChild: Child;

    constructor() {
        this.myChild = new Child();
        this.myChild.myParent = this;
    }
}

class Child {
    myParent: Parent;
}
```

Comment: No, they don't need to. OP made a comment disregarding another answer because they were in the same file.

Comment: So, is there something wrong with the OP's code, or should it work as it stands?

Comment: Nothing wrong with OP's code - I've updated my answer.