# IIFE and function hoisting - is not a function error

Tags: javascript, iife, hoisting

```
var Mod=(function () { say('hello'); 
             var say =  function (m){ console.log(m); }; 
              return ({a: 'b'}); }
 )();
```

VM3488:1 Uncaught TypeError: say is not a function(…)(anonymous function) @ VM3488:1(anonymous function) @ VM3488:1

but this works

```
var Mod = (function () { 
              say('hello');  
              function say (m){ console.log(m); };
              return ({a: 'b'}); }
     )();
```

why is this happening ? If I need to use "say" as a public function in my Mod, how is that going to work ?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the IIFE but read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887408/javascript-function-declaration-and-evaluation-order/3887590#3887590

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because *function expressions* are not *hoisted*. The first one is a a function expression and the second one is a *function statement* which is hoisted.

Also note that neither of your code snippets exports the `say` function so it remains as a *private* function.

Comment: thx for the quick reply. What pattern do I need to follow if I need to expose "say" as a public method ?

Comment: @KaPr It can be a method of the returned object: `return { say: say, a: 'b' }`. Or in ES2015: `return { say /* shorthand syntax */, a: 'b' }`

Answer (score 1):

Function expressions are not hoisted, which is why you are getting an error. You can move the expression before invocation and return the variable as a response to your IFFE. Now you can call say() in other places.

```js
var Mod=(function () { 
             var say =  function (m){ console.log(m); }; 
              say('hello'); 
              return {say: say}; 
})();

Mod.say("say what you want to say.");
```