# Arrow function called befor function defination get error

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions

```
console.log(addB(10, 15));

function addB(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(addC(10, 15));

const addC = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
};
```

Just convert function to arrow function. why get  "Cannot access 'addC' before initialization" error ..
affter that function line I call it its working. what is the limitation to use arrow function

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted. Assignments (of any kind of value) to variables are not.

Comment: arrow function are anonymous function associated to a variable, this means you can't access it before initialization juste like a variable

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887408/javascript-function-declaration-and-evaluation-order/3887590#3887590

Answer (score 1):

Arrow functions are not hoisted, so you cannot call them before you declare them.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```
console.log(addC(10, 15));

const addC = (a, b) => {
  return a + b;
};
```

You call `addC` and pass it as a parameter to `console.log` and then define `addC`. Therefore, when you `console.log(addC(10, 15));`, `addC` is not defined *yet*. You can move the call to `console.log` after the definition to solve the problem.