# Difference between function declarations

Tags: javascript, function, declaration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)
>   [What’s the difference in those declarations (in JavaScript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718842/whats-the-difference-in-those-declarations-in-javascript)

Is there any differences between the following function declarations:

```
function wtf() {

}

lol = function() {

}

omg: function() {

}
```

?

Regards

Comment: Please refer to this thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866084/javascript-function-declaration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- Is a regular function declaration.

2- You declare an anonymous function and you store it in a variable.

3- The last one is part of an object notation :

```
var obj = {
  omg:function(value){
    // some code here
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

1st one :

creates a function at page level ( global level u can say )

2nd : Assings the function to variable 'lol'

3rd: Syntax error. :P

Exactly similar to: 
[What's the difference in those declarations (in JavaScript)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718842/whats-the-difference-in-those-declarations-in-javascript)

Comment: The first one isn't necessarily global, it depends which scope it's defined in. Actually, in the example given, the second one is global, assuming the variable isn't scoped before.

Comment: @deceze: If first 2 declared inside a function: are not they exact equivalent?

Comment: @raghavv this link explains it a bit more clearly.

Comment: @raghavv Nope, try it: http://jsfiddle.net/UtTGG/

Comment: @raghavv, http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: @LPD thank you for the links and effort. It was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

No, it’s the quite the same thing for each of them.